# Fetch device logs using command line

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, logging, command-line

I'm working on a project that uses Xcode developer and command line tools, but does not use the Xcode GUI. The procedures omit the GUI for procedural reasons due to the contract, so we can't use it.

We can build from the command line using `xcodebuild`, perform intermediate steps like `codesign` and `lipo`, and install and APP or IPA using `fruitstrap` or `ideviceinstaller`.

The program creates detailed logs, and the logs are used to attest to proper execution. Are there any tools to fetch the logs from the device once the program completes its task? (We've given up on Apple-only tools, so third party tools are OK).

Jeff

Comment: Can you use idevicesyslog?